# Determine if a Process is Constantly Swapping Memory on Unix

Tags: memory

How does one go about determining if a process is constantly swapping memory on Unix? I'm using the top utility but I don't quite understand the details of that report.

Comment: Found a good article using vmstat: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8178

Comment: What Unix ? By the way, a process doesn't swap memory. That's the kernel which does it, and more precisely, the kernel reacts to page faults by paginating memory from the swap area to the RAM, and move RAM pages to the swap area should free RAM is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question is, whether the system is constantly swapping memory.

An active process, on it's own, might not swap a lot, while the system swaps other processes and data out to make space for it.

vmstat is a great tool for analysing virtual memory statistic.

```
qdot@valentha ~ $ vmstat       
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 3  0      0 5055564   1244 1651244    0    0   291   149  383  750  6  2 87  5
```

Comment: Based on the example output of vmstat you provided, could you perhaps walk me through what is happening on your system and what you typically look out for?

Comment: According to man vmstat, swpd refers to the amount of virtual memory being used. Is that also an indication of how much memory get "swapped" (swpd) by the system constantly?

Comment: no, that's 'si' and 'so' - swap in (to RAM) and swap out (to disk), respectively. I think that's listed in pages (4096 bytes, on x86), thou the manual is not terribly clear.

Comment: What does it mean for swpd be to be non-zero? Is it necessarily a bad thing if your system is always using a non-zero amount of virtual memory? I'm guessing it's faster for the system to hit the cache as opposed to virtual memory.

Comment: It just means the system had swapped something out. I generally prefer highly responsive desktops, so I tune mine so that swap is always the last-resort option. When I'm working with large files, I don't mind waiting longer when the file is in out of cache and needs to be fetched, but I do mind when VM made a wrong guess about application code. It usually just tries to balance out somehow. It really depends on a machine - I usually go for most RAM money can buy, so my 2y laptop's 8GB and desktop's 32GB.

Comment: On the other hand, there is a ton of dead code, and dead data (memory leaks sometimes are never accessed and can be swapped out) in typical usage - so if VM pressure is problematic (since you asked, it probably is), it's better to have it swapped out since it has no use in core memory.

Comment: I ran 'vmstat 5 10'and noticed that even thought swpd is non-zero, si and so are always zero. Does that actually make sense? If non-zero swpd in fact means "the system had swapped something out", can si and so be zero? Or is this because it's post- the fact that something was already swapped out?

Comment: It's exactly as you suspect - post the fact that something was already swapped out. si/so are in reference to the period of record.